# How to add Responsive Slider in Zerif Lite Wordpress Theme

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, responsive, nivo-slider

I've added slider in the big_title section using Nivo Slider plugin.
Slider is working fine but It's not responsive while the resolution decreases the slider remains the same size. 
These are the codes I added :

Here is the Css added,

```
@media screen and (max-width:1023px) {
.home-header-slider {
 padding-top: 111px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
.home-header-slider {
 padding-top: 0px;
}
}
 @media screen and (min-width:1024px) {
.home-header-slider {
 padding-top: 76px;
}
}
```

Code added in big_title.php template file

```
<div class="home-header-slider">
<?php nivo_slider( 1 ); ?>
</div>
```

I can't figure it out the error so please anyone tell me the correct code. Or is there any alternative to Nivo Slider do please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Nivo Slider --> Settings --> Slider Sizing
and select "Responsive"